# How can i insert a font from my local project in vue and vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, fonts, vuetify.js

i tried to add a font from my local project to vuetify and set that for main font but it does not work.
this is my project:
main folder
    public
    src
        assets
             font's
                  my font
                     iranyekan.css
    node modules

and this is my index.html in public

```
<style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "IranYekan";
        src: url("../assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("../assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.ttf") format("ttf"),
        url("../assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.woff") format("woff");
      }
    </style>
```

but it does not work. thanks

Comment: here you have a many ways.
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8169

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren i have a local font in my project. those way's  are for cdn's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try change your links to use:

```
@/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.ttf
or ~/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.ttf 
or ~@/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.ttf
```

I don't know how is your project, but vue reference the root directory with ~ or @, so do you can try?

```
<style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "IranYekan";
        src: url("~@/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("~@/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.ttf") format("ttf"),
        url("~@/assets/fonts/IranYekan/iranyekanwebregular.woff") format("woff");
      }
    </style>
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day, was fighting with it for quite a while. Now combined with varibles.scss as described here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/ it finally works!